# How to deal with OnClick + useState delay

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm doing React project for portfolio but lack of React study, I can't solve problem with useState asynchronous. when I clicked it once always display former result and changed when I clicked it twice.
I did use useEffect and setState(function) but it didn't work.

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { MovieInfoContextStore } from "../../contexts";

export default function BoxOffice({ isBoxOffice, setNotUpdatedInfos }) {
  const MovieInfosCtx = useContext(MovieInfoContextStore);

  const clickHandler = (v) => {
    const clickedTitle = v.target.innerText.replace(/1?2?3?4?5?./, "");
    MovieInfosCtx.setSearchMovieKeyword(clickedTitle); --> PROBLEM IS HERE
    const filteredTitle = MovieInfosCtx.boxesMoviesInfo?.find((e) => {
      return (
        e.titleEtc.substring(0, e.titleEtc.indexOf("^")) ==
        clickedTitle.replace(/ /g, "")
      );
    });
    if (filteredTitle !== undefined) {
      MovieInfosCtx.setMovieVal(filteredTitle);
      MovieInfosCtx.setDetailMovieInfos(true);
      setNotUpdatedInfos(false);
    } else {
      setNotUpdatedInfos(true);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      {isBoxOffice ? (
        <div className="w-[50%]">
          {MovieInfosCtx.isLoading ? (
            <h1 className="p-10 text-3xl">로딩중......</h1>
          ) : (
            <div className="w-full p-5 my-3 bg-white rounded-xl backdrop-filter backdrop-blur-md bg-opacity-10 border-gray-200 shadow-xl">
              {MovieInfosCtx.moviesInfo.map((movie, i) => (
                <div
                  className="p-2 my-1 bg-white backdrop-filter backdrop-blur-md bg-opacity-10 border-gray-200 shadow-md animate-fade-left duration-100 hover:bg-slate-200 cursor-pointer"
                  data-key={movie.movieCd}
                  key={movie.movieCd}
                  onClick={clickHandler}
                >
                  <h3 className="mx-10 my-3 text-3xl">
                    {i + 1}. {movie.movieNm}
                  </h3>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      ) : (
        <></>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

thanks for answers :)

any solutions or advice are welcome :)

Comment: Please share full code so people can help you easily

Comment: I can't see any `useState` in your code.

Comment: I use context API.

Comment: You need to use `useTransition` hook provide by `react`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue you are facing is related to asynchronous state updates. In React, state updates using hooks like useState are asynchronous, which means that the updated state may not be immediately reflected in subsequent lines of code.

To ensure that you are using the latest state value when updating the searchMovieKeyword, you can use a functional update with useState. Here's how you can modify your code to fix the issue:

```
    {MovieInfosCtx.moviesInfo.map((movie, i) => (
      <div
        className="p-2 my-1 bg-white backdrop-filter backdrop-blur-md bg-opacity-10 border-gray-200 shadow-md animate-fade-left duration-100 hover:bg-slate-200 cursor-pointer"
        data-key={movie.movieCd}
        key={movie.movieCd}
        onClick={(v) => {
          const clickedTitle = v.target.innerText.replace(/1?2?3?4?5?. /, "");
          MovieInfosCtx.setSearchMovieKeyword((prevKeyword) => clickedTitle);
        }}
      >
        {/* Render your movie information here */}
      </div>
    ))}
```

Comment: What does using _the functional update method_ change in this case?

Comment: thanks for your answer. but it still does not work at all.

Comment: You can define a function updateMovieDetails inside the useEffect hook. which will perform the logic to find the filtered title and update the relevant states. Then, you can call this function immediately within the useEffect hook to handle the state updates whenever clickedTitle changes. Hope it will work.